# How to get current row of input control like textbox within html table

Tags: jquery, checkbox, css-selectors, html-table

I am getting all checkboxes that are in an html table using this code and I need to find the current row in the table from the current checkbox.

```
            var checkboxes = $("form :checkbox");
            for (i = 0; i <= checkboxes.length; i++) {

                var checkbox = checkboxes[i];

                ///need to get current row in html table here 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var checkboxes = $("form :checkbox");
    for (i = 0; i <= checkboxes.length; i++) {

        var checkbox = checkboxes[i];

        var rowIndex = $(checkbox).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex;
    }
```

should do it

Comment: you got me in the right direction.  i updated your answer to the final solution

Comment: changed just slightly to use the index instead of the `get()` call (one less function call).